# Capturing image with avfoundation

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `AvFoundation` for camera.

This is my live preview:

[image]

It looks good. When user presses to "Button" I am creating a snapshot on same screen. (Like snapchat)

I am using following code for capturing image and showing it on the screen:

```
    self.stillOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection){
                        (imageSampleBuffer : CMSampleBuffer!, _) in

                        let imageDataJpeg = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageSampleBuffer)
                        let pickedImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageDataJpeg)!
                        self.captureSession.stopRunning()
                        self.previewImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
                        self.previewImageView.image = pickedImage
                        self.previewImageView.layer.zPosition = 100
}
```

After user captures an image screen looks like this:

[image]

Please look at the marked area. It wasn't looking on the live preview screen(Screenshot 1).

I mean live preview is not showing everything. But I am sure my live preview works well because I compared with other camera apps and everything was same as my live preview screen. I guess I have a problem with captured image.

I am creating live preview with following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
    for device in devices {
        // Make sure this particular device supports video
        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
            }
        }
    }
    if captureDevice != nil {
        beginSession()
    }
}

func beginSession() {
    let err : NSError? = nil
    do {
        try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
    } catch{

    }
    captureSession.addOutput(stillOutput)
    if err != nil {
        print("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer?.videoGravity=AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    self.cameraLayer.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
    previewLayer?.frame = self.cameraLayer.frame
    captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

My `cameraLayer` :

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. So it sounds like this layer is incorrectly placed or incorrectly sized, or it has the wrong AVLayerVideoGravity setting. Part of the image is off the screen or cropped; that's why you don't see that part of what the camera sees while you are previewing.

Comment: If you want more help, that is the part of your code we need to see: how are you creating the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and getting it onto the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

I used the

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
```

Instead of

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
```

Then problem fixed.